# Angular Select Tag with Bootstrap Dropdown Styling

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create custom styling for a select dropdown (including the options). The more I've dug into this, the more I've realized that styling options is quite difficult.
I'm currently using Bootstrap's dropdown and it works great, except for the fact that I have to use a function to assign a value.
This is how I am currently using a 'custom select dropdown':

```
<div class="form-element-container">     
    <div class="drop-down dropdown-toggle">       
        <label for="chooseAdvisor"></label>       
        <div>         
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{mySelection}}</button>         
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">           
                <li ng-repeat="option in options"><a href="" ng-click="setSelection(option)">{{option}}</a></li>       
            </ul>     
        </div>   
    </div> 
</div>
```

You can see that on click, I have to manually set the option in my controller rather than it being directly bound to my model. Is there any way that I can use Bootstrap's dropdown styling with angular's select tag?

I would love to be able to use my options repeater with 'track by', etc:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

Just a suggestion, I've not tested it yet.

Update answer:

I think you can instead of angular module : `acute-select`
https://github.com/john-oc/acute-select
Demo : http://john-oc.github.io/

Comment: The structure of that drop down is exactly the same issue I am facing. You have to add some sort of click event to set the model value which is what I am trying to avoid